# Print job cancelled at the printer

Tags: drivers, printing

My Epson 530 printer suddenly did not want to print any more.
I tried turning it on and off. Removing it, and adding it a few times.
I then downloaded the Imagescan package from Epson and ran the script. 
Now I have two of the same printer installed. One with the notion "driverless" added to it. The result is the same however, nothing will print. This is a network printer, and the other devices around the house can give it print jobs, -no questions asked.

"EPSON XP-530 Series, driverless, cups-filters 1.21.3" is the description of printer in CUPS.

I just found out that I can print anything from Libreoffice. If I just drag the PDF in question into there, I am able to print it. The same PDF will not print from firefox or docuiment viewer. Test page will also print!

Comment: command line `lpstat -l` lists printers and notices about pending tasks,

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to a similar issue I was having on the Ubuntu Forums, the solution was to setup the printer as an AppSocket device.

The procedure I followed when encountering the same error message with an Epson wireless printer was to:

- Open the printer settings window.
- Click the "Additional printer settings" button.
- Click on the "Add" button.
- Expand the network printer list and choose "AppSocket/HP JetDirect".
- Follow the instructions on the screen, entering the IP address of the printer and choosing a name/description for the printer.

This worked in my situation with an Epson ET-2650 and Ubuntu 18.04.